# How to pass hardcoded data in logstash input generated section

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

How to pass an hardcoded data from input generated, When I am passing this input through input section logstash is successfully executed but didnt produce any filtered output in console. Is there any way to pass json in input generator section??

Note- I have taken this input data from some log file...

```
input {
       generator { 
            lines => [\"clientContextId\":\"INTERNAL-b8d19563-94a1-442d-9a09-dde36743fb7d\",\"description\":\"A N1QL EXPLAIN statement was executed\",\"id\":28673,\"isAdHoc\":true,\"metrics\":{\"elapsedTime\":\"11.921ms\",\"executionTime\":\"11.764ms\",\"resultCount\":1,\"resultSize\":649},\"name\":\"EXPLAIN statement\",\"node\":\"127.0.0.1:8091\",\"real_userid\":{\"domain\":\"builtin\",\"user\":\"Administrator\"},\"remote\":{\"ip\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"port\":44695},\"requestId\":\"958a7e12-d5a6-4d7b-bd40-ac9bb60cf4a3\",\"statement\":\"explain INSERT INTO `Guardium` (KEY, VALUE) \\nVALUES ( \\\"id::5554\\n\\\", { \\\"Emp Name\\\": \\\"Test4\\\", \\\"Emp Company\\\" : \\\"GS Lab\\\", \\\"Emp Country\\\" : \\\"India\\\"} )\\nRETURNING *;\",\"status\":\"errors\",\"timestamp\":\"2021-01-07T09:37:00.486Z\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 (Couchbase Query Workbench (6.6.1-9213-enterprise))\"] 
                }
 }
filter{
// filter logic 
}
output{
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have JSON in a generator input. For example

```
input { generator { count => 1 lines => [ '{ "id": "43fb7d", "description": "..." }' ] } }
filter { json { source => "message" } }
```

will result in

```
"description" => "...",
         "id" => "43fb7d",
```

Comment: How to remove any warning message in the cmd which is generated by the logstash writting some code in filter section-

Generated message->  C:/Users/MayurGavali/Desktop/ELK/logstash-7.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib/awesome_print/formatters/base_formatter.rb:31: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

Comment: Nothing you change in the filter section will remove that. The awesome_print library is used by the rubydebug codec. If you remove that codec the library may not be loaded, so the warning may disappear. awesome_print was [fixed](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print/commit/d01fade4f2a090773ba8512ade456caf1e5cdbef#diff-0878c2bdc14bc32fc5bd2a67e357f140191ddb48258da0393e80ddb83a4780b6) years ago, but I do not think that change has been released.